# Let $f, g : [a,b] \to \mathbb R$ be two continuous functions such that $g(x) \le f(x)$ for all $x \in [a, b]$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, solution-verification, supremum-and-infimum, riemann-integration

> Let $f, g : [a,b] \to \mathbb R$ be two continuous functions such that $g(x) \le f(x)$ for all $x \in [a, b]$. Define
> $$\phi(x) =
> \begin{cases}
> f(x),  & x \in \mathbb Q \cap [a,b] \\
> g(x), & x \in [a,b] \setminus \mathbb Q
> \end{cases}$$
> show that
> $$\overline{\int_a^b} \phi = \int_a^b f  \\{\text{and}}\\ \underline{\int_a^b} \phi = \int_a^b g $$

What have i managed to do so far :

Case 1: $g(x)=f(x)$, then $$\overline{\int_a^b} \phi = \int_a^b f = \underline{\int_a^b} \phi = \int_a^b g $$

Case 2: $g(x) \lt f(x)$, let $P: a=t_0 \lt ... \lt t_n = b$

$ m_i = inf f\{ f(x): x \in [t_{i-1},t_i]\}$

$M_i = sup g\{ g(x): x \in [t_{i-1},t_i]\}$

then

$S(g,P) = \sum_{i=1}^n M_i (t_i - t_{i-1}) = sup g \sum_{i=1}^n (t_i - t_{i-1}) = sup g (b-a) $

$s(f,P) = \sum_{i=1}^n m_i (t_i - t_{i-1}) = inf f \sum_{i=1}^n (t_i - t_{i-1}) = inf f (b-a)$

$\overline{\int_a^b} \phi = inf f (b-a)$

$\underline{\int_a^b} \phi = sup g (b-a)$

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Hint: let $s$ be a simple function with $s \geqslant \phi$. Show that $s \geqslant f$. Similarly, if $s \leqslant \phi$, show that $s \leqslant g$.

Comment: Your two cases are not exhaustive. It's quite possible for $g(x)=f(x)$ for some $x$ while $g(x) < f(x)$ for other $x$. I'm guessing whatever proof you have when $g(x) < f(x)$ will work just fine when $g(x) = f(x)$.

Comment: @Andre: I don't know why you have the $\sup g$ and $\sup f$ in your formulas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any partition $P=[t_0,t_1,\dots,t_n]$ of $[a,b]$, because $\mathbb{Q}$ is a dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$, you can choose $s_1,s_2,\dots,s_n \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that  for all $k$
$$s_k \in [t_k,t_{k-1}]$$
So according to definition of upper Riemann integral
$$\overline{\int_{a}^b} \phi \ge \sum_{k=1}^n \phi(s_k)( t_k-t_{k-1})\stackrel{ s_i \in \mathbb{Q}}{=}\sum_{k=1}^n f(s_k)( t_k-t_{k-1})$$
for all choice of $P$ and $(s_i)$.
Besides, because $f$ is continuous hence it is Riemann integral on $[a,b]$. Hence as the norm(the mesh) of $P$ converges to $0$
$$\sum_{k=1}^n f(s_k)( t_k-t_{k-1}) \longrightarrow \int_{a}^b f$$
Thus,
$$\overline{\int_{a}^b} \phi  \ge \int_{a}^b f$$
On the other hand, $\phi \le f$, hence
$$\overline{\int_{a}^b}\phi \le \overline{\int_{a}^b } f = \int_{a}^b f$$
Thus
$$\overline{\int_{a}^b} \phi  = \int_{a}^b f$$

You can argue similarly with the other identity.